# number of distinct determinants under all permutations of the entries

Tags: permutations, determinant

I read from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A088021) that

> $\frac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^2}$ gives the number of distinct determinants of the generic $n \times n$ matrix whose entries are $n^2$ different indeterminates under all $(n^2)!$ permutations of the entries.

For example, when $n=2$, for indeterminates $a,b,c,d$, we have $ab-cd,ac-bd,ad-bc,bc-ad,bd-ac,cd-ab$. So $\frac{(2^2)!}{(2!)^2}=6$.

Comment: There are a total of $(n^2)!$ permutations of $n^2$ letters. When you rearrange the rows and columns, the determinant changes only its sign. There are $(n!)^2$ of such permutations.

Comment: The trouble with that @kabenyuk is that we want to divide $(n^2)!$ by the number of permutations fixing the determinant, and of your $(n!)^2$ only half are even permutations and so fix the determinant. We must also allow for the symmetry impose by $\det A=\det A^{T}$.